# C# midpoint round down option for decimal

Tags: c#, .net, math, rounding

Im working with an external payment system which uses a round down at exact midpoint, but round up if its anything more than that. I want to replicate the same in my application to match the value.

For example with two decimal point rounding, `150.415` is rounded to `150.41` and `150.4151` is rounded to `150.42`. I am not entirely sure what this rounding mechanism is called.

To replicate the same behaviour in C#, I tried using `Math.Round(amount, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)` and `Math.Round(amount, 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven)`, but both rounds off the above number to `150.42`
Trying to see what are my options here, including writing a custom function to do a similar rounding?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226137/discussion-on-question-by-keenuser-c-midpoint-round-down-option-for-decimal).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is the logic that you need:

```
public static decimal DigitalRiverRounding(decimal value)
{
    if (value < 0)
        return Math.Floor(value * 100 + 0.5m) / 100m;
    return Math.Ceiling(value * 100 - 0.5m) / 100m;
}
```

If you are certain no negative numbers are involved, you can of course remove the first two lines. I assumed for negative numbers the desired output is mirrored (`-150.415` => `-150.41`, so they compensate appropriately).

*Explanation assuming rounding with no decimals:* as `Ceiling` converts `1.01 - 2.00` to `2`, by doing `-0.5` you are translating that into a logic that does `0.51 - 1.50` to `1`, therefore `1.51 - 2.50` to `2`, which is what you need.

In case you need to use this everywhere in your app, you may want to use an extension method instead, which needs a separate static helper class:

```
public static decimal ToDigitalRiverRounding(this decimal value)
{
    if (value < 0)
        return Math.Floor(value * 100 + 0.5m) / 100m;
    return Math.Ceiling(value * 100 - 0.5m) / 100m;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
double roundN(double val, int len)
{
    double result;

    result = val * pow(10.0, len);
    result = static_cast<double>(static_cast<int>(result + 0.5));

    result = result * pow(10.0, -len);

    return result;
}

int main() {
    double a;
    cout<<"enter number"<<endl;
    cin>>a;
    a=roundN(a,2);
    std::cout << a;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you have walked into the wrong *language tag*.

Comment: I'm sorry I haven't noticed

Comment: @nareshgautam Try it for yourself - https://dotnetfiddle.net/